# why doesn't My C code on Fermat's little theorem run properly after 10?

Tags: c, math

I am a complete beginner and was just trying to apply what I have learned.

So I tried to make a C program that computes if a number passes the prime test in Fermat's little theorem.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double p, a, t;
  printf("Enter the number tested to be prime: ");
  scanf("%lf", &p);
  a = 1;
  t = 0;
  while (a <= p && t == 0) {
    t = pow(a, p) - a;
    t = (int)t % (int)p;
    a++;
  }
  if (t == 0) {
    printf("prime test passed");
  } else {
    printf("prime test failed");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So the problem is it works great until 10, but after that when I try it for 11 it just fails the test. Why is this happening?

Comment: You do know that one of the properties of prime numbers is that they are *integers*? So don't accept floating point value input or use floating point arithmetic or call floating point functions.

Comment: ...and (assuming you have fixed that) using `pow`  for integer calculations is not a very good idea

Comment: so can I declare my own power function without the math library and make it accept only integers?

Comment: Sure you can. Beware of overflows.

Comment: You may want to evaluate that power using modular arithmetic (and a wider type), though, otherwise it will overflow pretty fast.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Answer (score 1):

> for 11 it just fails the test. Why is this happening?

The reason for this concrete failure is likely not due to use of *floating point math*, but quite the contrary due to use of casting to an integer type by `(int)t` with a 4-byte `int`. In the course of your prime test, `double` `t` is assigned the value 8<sup>11</sup>−8 = 8589934584, which can well be held in `t`, but not in an `int` with a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>−1 = 2147483647.

Of course all this does not mean that you'll get much further if you just take this hurdle; soon you'd really encounter problems of floating point math. So the comment from Bob__ may indeed be a good advice.